# Preventing SQL Injections with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to be sure, that my SQL queries will be 100% safe.

If I use PDO named placeholders, is it possible for someone to achieve SQL injection?

Regarding to the documentation, using PDO, the query is sent first, and then the values, which basically means that it's not possible for injection, is that correct?

```
<?php
try {
    $DBH = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'root', '123456789');
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$data = array(
    'email' => $_POST['email'],
    'password' => md5($_POST['password']),
    'name' => $_POST['name']'
);

$STH = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO members (email, password, name) values (:email, :password, :name)");
$STH->execute($data);
?>
```

Also, it is safe to use root for the database authorization?

Comment: A better encrypt for the password with salt would be safer though

Comment: Sidenote: You have a syntax error `'name' => $_POST['name']'` remove the last quote. `'name' => $_POST['name']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes your understanding of PDO is correct - the data is automatically sanitised.

As for using root, I would create a user with the minimum possible permissions (read/write to one database). You may not have a security issue, but if you do you'll prevent a lot more by restricting access using permissions.

Answer (score 0):

So, you are practically asking us if documentation is correct?

Why only this part? There are billions of statements in the documentation. Why not to verify them all by means of asking a brand new question on Stack Overflow for each of them?

Comment: A note for the zeal policemen. If you don't like the answer - *may be* there is something wrong with the *question*  as well. Means why not to treat a question the same way as an answer? I will have no objections.

Comment: No, actually I'm sure that the documentation is correct. I just want to be sure, that there is no way to become injection victim, somehow.

Comment: There is *always* a way. Especially if your defence based not on the knowledge but on the assurance given by some anonymous uncredited person

Comment: If all hackers were thinking like you, the world would be much more secured. I cannot rely only on the developer's documentation. The hackers are finding backdoors, that are not known to the application authors. This is the reason I'm asking community developers, people who may know something.

Comment: Ahahah nice conspiracy :) It doesn't work this way, but who am I to dissipate your fantasies that are sooo romantic :)